# Hero jumps over walls after colliding with them

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, xcode7

In the following code, the 'hero' starts inside of the level. As it moves around the map, the black area outside of the map becomes visible. As the hero comes up to the wall he stops. But then, if I touch the black area outside of the level, the hero jumps over the wall and into the outside-of-the-level area. Also, sometimes when the hero contacts the wall he bounces back in the opposite direction. (I'm not really sure what is causing that.) What I'm trying to do is keep the hero inside the level, and stop the bouncing back that is happening sometimes.

I'm not sure if the issue is that I'm not doing my collisions correctly or if I need to somehow stop the black area from being visible at all. I think stopping the area outside of the level from showing is what I need but playing around with `let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)` and changing it to `let scene = GameScene(size: tileMap.frame.size)` didn't work. Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit

let tileMap = JSTileMap(named: "level2.tmx")
let hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hero")
let theCamera: SKCameraNode = SKCameraNode()

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    enum ColliderType: UInt32 {

        case Hero = 1
        case Wall = 2

    }


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

       self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
       self.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

        hero.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        hero.xScale = 0.5
        hero.yScale = 0.5
        hero.zPosition = 2

        hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: hero.size.height / 2)
        hero.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        hero.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
        hero.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Hero.rawValue
        hero.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Wall.rawValue
        hero.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Wall.rawValue


        tileMap.zPosition = 1


        tileMap.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.addChild(tileMap)
        self.addChild(hero)
        self.addChild(theCamera)

        self.camera = theCamera

        camera?.position = hero.position

        addWalls()


    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        print("Hero made contact with a wall")

    }


    func addWalls() {
        //Go through every point up the tile map
        for var a = 0; a < Int(tileMap.mapSize.width); a++ {
            //Go through every point across the tile map
            for var b = 0; b < Int(tileMap.mapSize.height); b++ {
                //Get the first layer (you may want to pick another layer if you don't want to use the first one on the tile map)
                let layerInfo:TMXLayerInfo = tileMap.layers[1] as! TMXLayerInfo
                //Create a point with a and b
                let point = CGPoint(x: a, y: b)
                //The gID is the ID of the tile. They start at 1 up the the amount of tiles in your tile set.
                let gid = layerInfo.layer.tileGidAt(layerInfo.layer.pointForCoord(point))

                //My gIDs for the floor were 2, 9 and 8 so I checked for those values
                if gid == 1 {
                    //I fetched a node at that point created by JSTileMap
                    let node = layerInfo.layer.tileAtCoord(point)
                    //I added a physics body
                    node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: node.frame.size)
                    node.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

                    node.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Wall.rawValue
                    node.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Hero.rawValue
                    node.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Wall.rawValue

                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let action = SKAction.moveTo(location, duration: 1)

            hero.runAction(action)


        }

            }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */


        let action = SKAction.moveTo(hero.position, duration: 0.25)
        theCamera.runAction(action)
    }
}
```

My TMX file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="24" height="42" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" nextobjectid="13">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="grass-tiles-2-small" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" tilecount="72">
  <image source="grass-tiles-2-small.png" trans="ff00ff" width="384" height="192"/>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="Tile Layer 1" width="24" height="42">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
   eJztzLEJAAAMw7Bs/f/jXhHIIINXJf2uNJ/P5/P5fD6fz+fz+Ut+swfI8xgR
  </data>
 </layer>
 <layer name="Walls" width="24" height="42">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
   eJztzLEJAAAMw7Dk/6d7RaCDDF7VJB2/is/n8/l8Pp/P5/P5/E/+8gMA/ACB
  </data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

Here is a video of both the bouncing when the hero touches the wall and the jumping over the wall [Video of app sim](https://youtu.be/LdI1KiTaKFI)

Comment: Without seeing the tile map, it is hard to say what is wrong. Can you upload your level2.tmx somewhere and It is easier to find the problem then.

Comment: I edited my post again, this time I added a video I made of the app. In the video you can see the bouncing and the jumping over walls I talked about.

Comment: Hang on, I am testing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a contact happens between a node and a physics body, SpriteKit will just detect the contact but won't take responsibility for stopping the node's action as we hitting an obstacle in the daily life. So you need to stop it manually.

Let's add a key value for `SKAction` of `hero` to distinguish the moving action from other actions which may be added in the future:

```
hero.runAction(action, withKey: "move")
```

Then, modify `didBeginContact` method to remove the action when contact happens, and I hope this will make what you want:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("Hero made contact with a wall")
    // Stop your hero
    hero.removeActionForKey("move")
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, not sure why I was thinking sprite-kit would handle the stop. Thanks!